# Button bug only on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari

The site that I am currently working on has a problem with a slider that I made, and it's driving me crazy.

Under the part called "Selected Customers" on [this site](https://www.ignite.no/en/), when on any ios device the arrows inside the buttons are wrongly placed and the button either does not work at all or very poorly.

I suspect that it's a problem with css support or css defaults for IOS-devices, because I don't run into the same problem on any other device. It happens on both chrome and safari. After debugging through my free trial on browserstack I couldn't really figure it out, and I can't afford to pay for a subscription.

This is the scss I wrote, where I think the fault lies:

```css
.slideshow-customers{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-basis:auto;
  position:relative;
  #left-slide, #right-slide{
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:2;
    background:white;
    border:0;
    color:#18243f;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 1px rgba(204,204,204,0.6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height:1.8em;
    font-size:1.8em;
    height:1.8em;
    width:1.8em !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:flex;
    & .fas.fa-chevron-left, & .fas.fa-chevron-right{
      margin:auto;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      color:  rgba(24,36,63,0.8);
    }
    & .fas.fa-chevron-left{
      transform:translateX(-2px) !important;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2px,0,0) !important;
      -ms-transform: translateX(-2px) !important;
    }
    & .fas.fa-chevron-right{
      transform:translateX(2px) !important;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(2px,0,0) !important;
      -ms-transform: translateX(2px) !important;
    }
  }
```

Any insight is highly appreciated!

Comment: In your `right()` function, you're passing an invalid selector to the first invocation of `querySelector()`. Try fixing that first and then see if you're still having trouble with the button behaviors.

Comment: @raviramani it's the same error that DisableR pointed out in their answer. It's not a JavaScript syntax error -- it's a CSS one. Some browser may be more flexible than others in their fallback behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS Safari applies a `1em` horizontal padding by default to its button elements. Since your buttons' font-size is quite large (`1.8em` of `16px` equals ~`29px`), this padding is causing the width of the button to expand to ~`58px` (`29px` * 2), and pushing the inner icon off-center.

For your purposes, resetting the padding may be enough to get what you're looking for:

```
.slideshow-customers {
  ...
  #left-slide, #right-slide {
    ...
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the most logical answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In order to center the chevrons, instead of hardcoding exact offset in pixels, make it to be the percent to width:

`-webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0) !important;`

When I tap on the button, there is an error in web inspector:
[image]

I am not frontend dev, but maybe this can point onto the exact problem for you.

You can debug your web site with desktop Safari and iOS device or iOS Simulator.
https://support.brightcove.com/debugging-mobile-devices